# Loop over two lists

Tags: c#, list, loops

I have 2 lists

- `List1`
- `List2`

How can I continue looping through `List2` until I reach the end of `List1`? So, if I get to the end of `List2` before the end of `List1`, start over and loop through `List2` again. Once I reach the end of List1 I want to break out of both loops and continue with the rest of the program. I need a different item from each of the lists each time.

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you mean. From what I understand, you essentially wanna loop through both lists at the same time?

Comment: Provide some sample in and output to show what the desired result would be

Comment: Is it possible that `List2` will be _empty_?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a for loop do iterate over List1. With the modulo operator, you can make sure that your index is never bigger than the count of List2.

```
for (int i = 0;i < List1.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("List1: " + List1[i]);
    Console.WriteLine("List2: " + List2[i % List2.Count]);
}
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oL834n